# Function read() returns 0 when doing socket communications under Linux

Tags: c++, linux, http, sockets

[image]

The image linked above is the HTML that browser shows. Every time when I press a link, the server cannot accept the correct HTTP information from the browser. Below is my code related to communicating through HTTP.

```
char buf[2048];
http_handle hh(connfd, buf, 2048);
read(connfd, buf, 2048);
hh.handle_http_request(&hh);
hh.response_http_request(&hh);    //the first two function works

read(connfd, buf, 2048);          //this returns 0
hh.handle_http_request(&hh);
hh.response_http_request(&hh);
```

Below is the implementation of `handle_http_request`and`response_http_request`:

```c
void* http_handle::handle_http_request(void* arg) {
    http_handle* hp = (http_handle*)arg;
    hp->_handle_http_request();
    return hp;
}

void http_handle::_handle_http_request() {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; this->buf[i] != ' '; i++)
        method[i] = this->buf[i];
    method[i] = 0;

    for (j = 0, ++i; this->buf[i] != ' '; i++, j++)
        url[j] = this->buf[i];
    url[j] = 0;

    //method stores http operations like GET and POST
    //url stores the url resource in the http start line

    if (!strcasecmp(method, "GET")) {
        //...
    }
    if (!strcasecmp(method, "POST")) {
        //...
    }
}

void* http_handle::response_http_request(void* arg) {
    http_handle* hp = (http_handle*)arg;
    hp->_response_http_request();
    return hp;
}

void http_handle::_response_http_request() {
    if (strcasecmp(method, "GET") && strcasecmp(method, "POST")) {
        unimpelented();
        return;
    }
    if (!strcasecmp(method, "GET")) {
        if (strcmp(url, "/") == 0) {
            char tmp_path[256];
            http_handle::path = getcwd(tmp_path, 256);
            trans_dir("src");
            return;
        }

        std::string filepath = http_handle::path + "/" + url;
        struct stat filestat;
        if ((stat(filepath.c_str(), &filestat)) != 0) {
            perror("_response_http_request stat error");
            exit(1);
        }

        switch (filestat.st_mode & S_IFMT) {
            case S_IFREG:
                trans_file(filepath);
                break;
            case S_IFDIR:
                trans_dir(filepath);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return;    
    }
    if (!strcasecmp(method, "POST")) {  //to be implemented

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't tag questions featuring C++ code with the C tag; doing so is more likely to earn you downvotes than plaudits.

Comment: sorry about that, i am just new to this community. Won't do that

Comment: Thanks — mistakes of that kind are normal for newcomers.  If you learn from the mistake, there won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

`read()` returns 0 when EOF is reached, ie when the peer has closed the TCP connection on its end.

The data you have shown is not larger than your buffer, so the first `read()` receives all of the data, and there is nothing left for the second `read()` because the server closed the connection after sending the data.

Comment: I tried multiple times, the program terminated with SIGPIPE signal. Now i am wonder why browser ends connection as i add "Connection: keep-alive" in the http headers.

Comment: the gdb information is below
`(gdb) 

Program received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe.
0x00007ffff7ce7530 in __libc_send (fd=7, buf=0x7fffffff96a0, len=2, flags=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/send.c:28
28 ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/send.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 

Program terminated with signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe.
The program no longer exists.
`

Comment: @Torch requesting `Connection: keep-alive` is merely a *suggestion*, the server is under no obligation to honor it. If it wants to close the connection after sending the response, it will. Look at the `Connection` header in the response to know if it actually is or not.. As for the socket error, you really should disable `SIGPIPE` signals on any socket you create.